# Bootstrap Button Toggle - Form Values?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

There seems to be a load of questions about this, but none that give a definitive *simple* answer.

My understanding is that the Twitter Bootstrap Button Toogle is intended to 'act' in the same way as a checkbox.  On that basis, my assumption is that it should be possible to use it in that same way.  I can't however, find a way of passing these 'checkbox' values in the form.  Regardless of whether the buttons are toggled on or off, the form 'dump' isn't showing either the field name or a value when posted.

I've seen hints that I should be looking at jQuery to find these values, but I haven't found a simple example that concentrates on just that issue (and my JS knowledge is still somewhat limited!).  I am however using AjaxForm to process the form, which may help.

My existing code below (other, simple, form elements removed for clarity)...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#addshare').ajaxForm(
{ 
target: '#shares', 
beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
success: function() { 
$('#shares').fadeIn('slow'); 
} 
});
function showRequest() { 
$('#shares').html('<p class="alert alert-success">Processing...</p>'); 
} 
});
</script>

<form id="addshare" method="post" action="/a/share/">
 <div class="control-group" id="sharewithgroup"> 
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" data-toggle-name="sharewith">
   <button class="btn" id="share1" name="share1" value="1" type="button">Share 1</button>
   <button class="btn" id="share1" name="share2" value="2" type="button">Share 2</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I guess you could just use jQuery to get the "value" attribute of the button that has been clicked?

Comment: @Billy - thanks for the reply. I did consider that (using an onclick), however my limited JS knowledge means I have no idea how to handle the toggle aspect (ie if the user clicked twice)